# Internationalization autocomplete JS variable

Tags: plugins, javascript, translation, autocomplete

I'm working in a plugin (My first plugin) that uses autocomplete (Via JQuery UI) via an array and I'm wondering if I have to translate the array too if I want to make my plugin fully translatable.

```
jQuery(function(){ 
   let supportedServices = [
    'Academia', 'Airbnb', 'Amazon', 'AppStore', 'Bandcamp', 'Blogger',
   ];

   jQuery('#service_name ').autocomplete({
    source: supportedServices,
    classes: {
     "ui-autocomplete": "contactmefy_ui_autocomplete"
    },
    select: SomeFunction,
   });
});
```

In that case, it's a good idea to use the new wp-i18n JavaScript package?
[Internationalization in WordPress 5.0](https://pascalbirchler.com/internationalization-in-wordpress-5-0/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And I'm wondering if I have to translate the array too if I want to
>   make my plugin fully translatable.

It wouldn't be *fully* translatable if you didn't, would it? So yes, you need to make these translatable for that to be true.

> In that case, it's a good idea to use the new wp-i18n JavaScript
>   package? [Internationalization in WordPress 5.0](https://pascalbirchler.com/internationalization-in-wordpress-5-0/)

It could be, yes. The previous way, which still works, is what `wp_localize_script()` is for. For example, if you enqueue this script like this:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-plugin', // etc. etc.
```

Then you can provide translatable strings like this:

```
wp_localize_script(
    'my-plugin',
    'myPlugin',
    [
        'supportedServices' => [
            __( 'Academia', 'my-plugin' ),
            __( 'Airbnb', 'my-plugin' ),
            __( 'Amazon', 'my-plugin' ),
            __( 'AppStore', 'my-plugin' ),
            __( 'Bandcamp', 'my-plugin' ),
            __( 'Blogger','my-plugin' ),
        ],
    ]
);
```

The supported service names would now be translatable in PHP, but you can access them in JavaScript like this:

```
let supportedServices = myPlugin.supportedServices;
```

Comment: Thanks! I was worried about asking something too obvious. I guess that I try the wp_localize_script way. Thank you again!.